# Color Picker Crash

Tags: iphone, ipad

In my application user has an option to change his background by choosing an image or by selecting a color from color picker. When ever he chooses background color its working fine, but when he changes the background with an image and next with some background color it is crashing.

Below is the crash report:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICGColor red], /sdf/sdfs/fsdf/sdf/sdf/Utilities/UIColor-Expanded.m:131

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Must be an RGB color to use -red'
```

I am using UIColor-HSVAdditions, UIColor-Expanded files, please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code you are using, it's really difficult to answer your question thoroughly. So, post the code where you are using `UIColor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `[myColor canProvideRGBComponents]` return false?

Also, try `NSLog("%@", myColor);`

Comment: color canProvideRGBComponents 1
 color UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1

Comment: color canProvideRGBComponents 0 .. color kCGColorSpaceModelPattern 1 .. when it returned false it got crashed

Comment: now I have included this - (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color {
    if([color canProvideRGBComponents]) { // Do something } ... condition now the app is not crashing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **`UIColor`** like this: `[UIColor redColor];`.